# i am getting Permission denied error when i upload image on firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am working on Firebase image upload. but facing an error in my rules of storage.

```
       rules_version = '2';
       service firebase.storage {
      match /b/savephoto-a1cc3.appspot.com/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
  // Allow access by all users
  allow read, write;
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: this.angularFireStorage.upload("/files"+Math.random(),file)

i am using this in angular.

Comment: Have you implemented authentication?

Comment: yes, of course, .this error comes when i hit to upload an image on firebase. i also using google login using firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say that you have already implemented Firebase Authentication, then the following rules will do the trick:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{files} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to have data validation as well, please check the official documentation:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security#data_validation